# pod react-native-image-crop-picker failed in mac based on M1

Tags: react-native

I need a mulitple image picker, so I found the react-native-image-crop-picker lib and installed it. but when I use npx pod-install or run the pod install in ios directory, it showed the error below:

```
[!] Error installing TOCropViewController
[!] /usr/bin/git clone https://github.com/TimOliver/TOCropViewController.git /var/folders/dh/mnrtx44j2813tnj3kj_rngvw0000gn/T/d20231114-5160-frh25m --template= --single-branch --depth 1 --branch 2.6.1

Cloning into '/var/folders/dh/mnrtx44j2813tnj3kj_rngvw0000gn/T/d20231114-5160-frh25m'...
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/TimOliver/TOCropViewController.git/': Failed to connect to github.com port 443 after 75029 ms: Couldn't connect to server

Couldn't install Pods. Updating the Pods project and trying again...
Command `pod install` failed.
└─ Cause: Error installing TOCropViewController
[!] /usr/bin/git clone https://github.com/TimOliver/TOCropViewController.git /var/folders/dh/mnrtx44j2813tnj3kj_rngvw0000gn/T/d20231114-5160-frh25m --template= --single-branch --depth 1 --branch 2.6.1

Cloning into '/var/folders/dh/mnrtx44j2813tnj3kj_rngvw0000gn/T/d20231114-5160-frh25m'...
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/TimOliver/TOCropViewController.git/': Failed to connect to github.com port 443 after 75029 ms: Couldn't connect to server
```

I tried to use pod install and npx pod-install, it failed. I think it means that I can go through for the github website behind the proxy or net things. is there anyone meet the same problem as me? it there any solution for that, thanks. :)